# Interface-based projections, native queries and Enums

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

After upgrading to Hibernate 6 and Spring Boot 3 the following throws me an error (`Cannot project java.lang.Short to com.cubetrek.cubetrekplayground.database.TrackData$Sharing; Target type is not an interface and no matching Converter found`).

The @Entity class is as follows:

```
@Entity(name = "trackdata")
@Table(name = "trackdata")
public class TrackData implements Serializable {

    public enum Sharing {
        PRIVATE, FRIENDS, PUBLIC;
    }

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    @Column(name = "sharing")
    private Sharing sharing;
    
    // loads of other fields and getters and setters...

    //and here's the interface
    
    public interface TrackMetadata {
        Long getId();
        @JsonSerialize(using = TitleSerializer.class, as=String.class)
        String getTitle();

        @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
        Sharing getSharing();
    }
}
```

In the TrackDataRepository:

```
public interface TrackDataRepository extends JpaRepository<TrackData, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<TrackData> {
    Optional<TrackData> findById(Long id);
    
    // and here's the query in question:
    @Query(value = "SELECT trackdata.id, trackdata.title, trackdata.sharing FROM trackdata " +
            "WHERE trackdata.id = :trackid", nativeQuery = true)
    TrackData.TrackMetadata getMetadata(long trackid);
}
```

The Entity works as intented:

```
    TrackData trackData = trackDataRepository.getReferenceById(21682L);
    System.out.println(trackData.getSharing()); //works fine
```

but the interface is screwed up:

```
TrackData.TrackMetadata td2 = trackDataRepository.getMetadata(21682L);
System.out.println(td2.getTitle()); //works
System.out.println(td2.getSharing()); //ERROR!!
```

And the error seems to be because of the projection from short to enum:

**`Cannot project java.lang.Short to com.cubetrek.cubetrekplayground.database.TrackData$Sharing; Target type is not an interface and no matching Converter found`**

---

Also a custom Converter doesn't seem to do the trick:

```
    @Converter
    public static class SharingConverter implements AttributeConverter<Sharing, Short> {
        @Override
        public Short convertToDatabaseColumn(Sharing sharing) {
            return (short)sharing.ordinal();
        }

        @Override
        public Sharing convertToEntityAttribute(Short dbData) {
            return Sharing.values()[dbData];
        }
    }
```

```
    public interface TrackMetadata {
        Long getId();
        @JsonSerialize(using = TitleSerializer.class, as=String.class)
        String getTitle();

        @Convert(converter = SharingConverter.class)
        Sharing getSharing();
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the `getReferenceById` method inside `TrackDataRepository`

Comment: That's inherited from `JpaRepository`, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#getReferenceById(ID)
It also works by using `trackDataRepository.getById(21682L)`

Comment: What is the database type of Sharing enum?

Comment: It's a SMALLINT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workaround solution to solve this. Mark your converter class as a bean with `@Component`.

```
@Component
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class SharingConverter implements AttributeConverter<Sharing, Short> {
  @Override
  public Short convertToDatabaseColumn(Sharing sharing) {
    return (short)sharing.ordinal();
  }

  @Override
  public Sharing convertToEntityAttribute(Short dbData) {
    return Sharing.values()[dbData];
  }
}
```

Then use SpEL through `@Value` to convert `Short` to enum.

`target` is an identifier that will be bound to the "aggregate root backing the projection" (Spring Data Jpa docs, section "An Open Projection").

```
  public interface TrackMetadata {
    Long getId();

    String getTitle();

    @Value("#{@sharingConverter.convertToEntityAttribute(target.sharing)}")
    Sharing getSharing();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, that solves it! I would have never arrived at this solution...
Is this some bug in JPA that such a workaround is required, or what am I missing here?

Comment: Great, This is an interface projection, JPA only supports the Entities. I cannot say that this is a JPA bug and I cannot find any related documents.